# Segmenting License Plate Characters #ImageProcessing

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, image-segmentation

For a university project I have to segment characters from a license plate using Python. This sounds reasonably simple. However, the thing is that we are not allowed to use any sophisticated library functions such as cv2.findContours(). The basics such as cv2.imread() cv2.resize() cv2.rectangle() are allowed.

I have written a function that localizes a license plate in an image and outputs a result as can be seen in the images [Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhHz2.png) and [Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGSHa.png) . These are binary images.

As one can see. Sometimes, the output of this function is relatively clean ([Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGSHa.png)).  However, often it is also noisy ([Output 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhHz2.png))

For a clean image ([Output 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGSHa.png)) I have tried finding the columns that contain less than x black pixels in order to segment the characters. However, this only works when the image is clean. This is often not the case. Changing the x parameter here does not make significant improvement.

Does anybody have suggestions on how I can approach this problem?

Comment: I would look after small areas in the image and remove them. Example: A black area is just 4 pixels big, so this has to be noise. When a particular threshold is reached the area is detected as a number or letter.

Comment: @ChristianYami: as the findContours function is not allowed, getting the areas is not that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an elementary solution, you can form a profile by counting the black pixels on all vertical lines. Then look for maximas and minimas of the average count in a sliding interval on this profile. The interval length should be a fraction of the expected width of a character. Only the extrema with sufficient contrast should be considered.

To avoid the effect of surrounding features in rotated plates, you can restrict the counting to just a slice of the image.

[image]

Once you have approximate vertical limits between the characters, you can repeat a similar processing to get the bottom and top limits of the characters (the sliding interval is no more necessary).

Finally, you can refine the boxing by finding the horizontal limits in the rectangles so formed.

[image]

Comment: This is genius! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @codefreak287. Thanks. The most critical step is the first splits. IMO, relying on the height of the white sections is the most reliable.